# Could someone explain why my code is not working properly?

Tags: python, if-statement, range

i am doing a challenge but for some reason every time i run it says 3 outta of 7 test cases are incorrect and don't know why? everything seems in order. Here is the challenge if Task
Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If  is odd, print Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive 2 range of 5 to , print Not Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If  is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

***My code below:***

```
n = int(input().strip())
if n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    if n % 2 == 1 and n in range(2,5):
        print("Not Weird")

    elif n % 2 == 1 and n in range(6,20):
        print("Weird")

    elif n > 20:
        print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Are `5` and `20` exclusive or inclusive in the range in the question?

Comment: They are inclusive

Comment: Your condition for "even" is wrong and actually unnecessary at all because "odd" was handled already.

Comment: could you please explain to me a little in depth why i am incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
n = int(input().strip())
if n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    if n in range(2,6):
        print("Not Weird")

    elif n in range(6,21):
        print("Weird")

    elif n > 20:

 print("Not Weird"
```

Answer (score 0):

To include 5 and 20 in range you need to specify it as `number` + `1`. Range does not include the last number. Also, there is no need to check for even condition every time in the else part as the control jumps to `else` when `if` fails!.

```
n = int(input().strip())
if n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    if n in range(2,6):
        print("Not Weird")

    elif n in range(6,21):
        print("Weird")

    elif n > 20:
        print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: okay so i was just basically off by +1 into my range that's what was throwing off my code?

Comment: Yes, those test cases might have covered the edge values!